# matlab like struct in python

Tags: python, matlab, list, struct

Can you suggest clean way to represent this struct in python?

```
students = struct;
students(1).fname = 'john';
students(1).lname ='smith';
students(1).height = 180;

students(2).fname = 'dave';
students(2).lname = 'clinton';
students(2).height = 184;
```

Thanks!

Comment: list of dictionaries or a list of a student class

Comment: can you please show an example?

Comment: I just wrote a class (named "tree") that makes possible to use the matlab-like syntax in python3. For the initial example, we could write something like: students = tree() students.john.lname ='smith' students.john.height = 180 students.dave.lname = 'clinton' students.dave.height = 184 students.other.lname = 'roger' students.other.height = 185 Let me know if someone if interested in having the source code of the "tree" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can accomplished by creating a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
students = [
    {'fname': 'john', 'lname': 'smith', 'height': 180},
    {'fname': 'dave', 'lname': 'clinton', 'height': 184}
]
```

Then, you can get the n-th student by doing `students[n]` or a specific field from the n-th student by doing `students[n]['fname']`

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can make a class (which is a bit like a struct but with more functionality) as follows:

```
class Student()
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, height):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.height = height
```

The __init__ function describes the information required to make a new student record. The 'self' argument just tells Python that you want to set these variables on an instance (an actual student record) rather than on the class (Which is a blueprint for student records). You can then create an instance of a Student as follows:

```
my_student = Student('Space', 'Man', 180)
```

You could make many of these instances and append each to a list:

```
all_students = [] # An empty list
all_students.append(my_student) # using the instance we've already created
all_students.append(Student('Jingle', 'Sting', 180)) # a new instance
```

You can then access the items in the list as follows:

```
all_students[1]
```

By creating a class, you can also create methods which apply to all instances of Students.

```
class Student()
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, height):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.height = height

    def get_height_in_meters(self):
        return self.height / 100
```

And use them like this:

```
my_student.get_height_in_meters()
```

You could even string accessing student records from the list directly with methods that apply to them like so:

```
all_students[1].get_height_in_meters()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of namedtuple(s):

```
import collections
harry = student(fname="harry", lname="Potter", height=160)
hermione = student(fname="hermione", lname="Granger", height=140)

students = [
    harry,
    hermione
]
print(students[0].fname)
print(students[1].fname)
```